# Custom content outside The_content loop

Tags: seo, search-engines

I have inserted code in single.php to get custom fields and custom taxonomies. That is something like;

```
    <?php the_title()?>
    <?php the_content()?>
    [custom fields]
    [Custom taxonomies]
    Address: [address]
    Phone: [phone]
    Email: [email]
    Web: [website]
```

My question is: the lines outside the_content are equally valued by search engines or this data should be within the_content() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WordPress Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) is an internal feature of WordPress and therefore has no effect on Google or any other major search engine. However, elements outside of the loop that are **repeated** on every page will be treated differently to what the main content is, this is normal and effects all websites no matter the platform they decide to use.

Comment: Thanks Simon. These are directory listings and contact info on each post is different. So is it fine to do this way or should i include in the loop? Thanks

Comment: It's absolutely fine to repeat address information, in fact its encouraged for local rankings. I even [repeat mine in the header](https://www.bybe.net), most people repeat it in the footer, either are ok because Google and other search engines understand surrounding elements and content.

Comment: Thanks, Much appreciated:) In my case, values for address, phone, email and website url are different on each page because it's a directory website and values are different for each business. Thanks